# Multithreaded malloc for MSVC

Tags: c++, multithreading

> Memory allocation performance in single and multithreaded environments
>   is an important aspect of any application. Some allocators, such as
>   malloc in the Solaris Operating System, work best with single-threaded
>   applications. However, a different approach must be taken when
>   designing an allocator optimized for a multithreaded application.

This http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/multiproc/multiproc.html overview shows some considerable performance gains over malloc.

What is the mtmalloc equivalent for MSVC?

Comment: @Tudor Yes, Visual C++ 2010 to be exact.

Comment: Windows has what is called [Low-fragmentation Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (enabled by default from Vista), which is supposed to benefit multithreaded applications. You might want to test compared to other options though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of Windows having any default memory allocator for multithreaded scenarios, but you can find a good suite of memory allocators optimized for multiple threads in Intel TBB: http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00235.html